# Model reference with C S-functions in Accelerator mode

Tags: simulink, s-function

I would like to prepare a `Simulink` file for a real-time target. In the main `Simulink` file I have a `Model` reference block, which I set to run in `Accelerator` mode. The `Model` block also contains several `S-functions`. The `Model` file was also configured to use a fixed-step solver.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by:
    Error using do_rt (line 410)
    The noninlined S-function 'whatever/Model' in a referenced model is not allowed
    to call macros that use the generic function in the SimStruct. To find such macros,
search for GenericFcn in simstruc.h
```

when building for the `SIM` target.

Everything works well if I switch to `Normal` mode for the `Model` block.

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found my answer. Here are the limitations of S-functions + Model reference:
http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/ug/using-s-functions-with-model-referencing.html#bsp24qn-6

> A referenced model cannot use noninlined S-functions in the following cases:
>
> - The model uses a variable-step solver.
> - Simulink Coder™ generated the S-function.
> - The S-function supports use of fixed-point numbers as inputs, outputs, or parameters.
> - The model is referenced more than once in the model reference hierarchy. To work around this limitation, use Normal mode.
> - The S-function uses string parameters.

Comment: I didn't know string parameters are not supported.